How to loop though dplyr group_by and summarize statements for list of variables
I'm trying to create multiple two may summary tables from a list of variables. Ideally I'd then like to append those tables.
My dataframe looks like this with multiple demographic variables, one ID variable, and one binary variable identifying whether the year was a targeted intervention year:



ID
Gender
Race
AgeCategory
TargetYear




1234
Male
White
18-25
1


5675
Female
Asian
30-35
0



I'm trying to create crosstab summaries for every combination of TargetYear and the demographic variables (TargetYear + Gender, TargetYear + Race, etc.) I know I can likely do this in a loop or function but haven't had success so far.
I initially tried to approach this with a combination of a for loop and dplyr summary after defining the variables:
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

variables <- c("Gender", "Race", "AgeCategory")

agg <- NULL

for (i in variables){
  u <- df %>% group_by(TargetYear, (i)) %>% summarize(n=n_distinct(ID)) %>% ungroup() %>% mutate(total=sum(n)) %>% group_by(TargetYear, (i)) %>% pivot_longer((i))
  return(u)
  bind_rows(agg, u)
}

Where I was expecting:



TargetYear
n
total
name
value




1
5
30
Gender
Male


0
10
30
Gender
Male


1
3
30
Gender
Female


0
12
30
Gender
Female


1
10
50
Race
White


0
20
50
Race
White


1
23
50
Race
Asian


0
27
50
Race
Asian



And instead just got a NULL agg and a u with this:



TargetYear
(i)
n
total




0
Gender
15
30


1
Gender
15
30



I am very new to loops and functions so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here. Any help would be appreciated! Especially solutions utilizing loops and functions.

would be nice to have a sample data

There are a few problems with your loop, but one of the biggest is that you aren't assigning bind_rows() to anything. I think you mean to do agg <- bind_rows(agg, u). Also, return(u) is unnecessary here and your pipe chain errors for me. (i) isn't the right tidyverse syntax for substituting a column name.

No need to loop:
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df |>
  pivot_longer(Gender:AgeCategory) |>
  mutate(total = n_distinct(ID))  |>
  summarize(n = n(), total = unique(total), .by = c(name, value, TargetYear))
#   name        value  TargetYear     n total
#   <chr>       <chr>       <int> <int> <int>
# 1 Gender      Male            1     1     2
# 2 Race        White           1     1     2
# 3 AgeCategory 18-25           1     1     2
# 4 Gender      Female          0     1     2
# 5 Race        Asian           0     1     2
# 6 AgeCategory 30-35           0     1     2

